# How can we compute the 6 missing numbers?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image]

There are 3 datatables. We forgot the numbers around the third square. How can we compute the 6 missing  numbers?(there are question marks instead of them)

Comment: Are those things on the border of square 3 that look like 2's the question marks?  This belongs on puzzling.se

Comment: No those are question marks.

Comment: 142 down the left, 677 along the bottom.  This is a way of multiplying by hand.

Comment: @BarryCipra [A lovely, but damn *old* way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napier%27s_bones) :-) Veritas, have also a look at [lattice multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_multiplication)

Comment: Just in case somebody is brave enough: [lattice multiplication in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173124/lattice-or-per-gelosia-multiplication-how-to-avoid-the-use-of-the-fp-package). I'm not sure it's possible in MathJaX, though.

Comment: I'm still do not understand  why is it 142 and 677. Can you explain it in details?

Comment: @Veritas What is $274\times859$? How is it related to your first square? What is $892\times673$? What if you consider the digits in each square to be a two digit number? What if you add digits in the same diagonals an take carry into account? Really, reading Wikipedia is *that* difficult?

Comment: @Veritas, I thought you were just sharing a puzzle (which is more or less discouraged here).  But if you really have a question about what's going on with these tables, please edit your posting to provide some context, including your own ideas about what the tables mean, and someone will be glad to answer.

Comment: As the OP does not appear to know the answer and is asking for an explanation, I suggest this should be migrated back to Math.SE

Comment: @Joe I'm curious, is asking for an explanation of the answer to a mathematical puzzle not on-topic here?

Comment: @Emrakul it's not a puzzle. It's a well-known, accepted mathematical process for multiplying two numbers. Is [long multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_multiplication) a puzzle? I wouldn't say it is, I'd say it's math (and probably homework, fwiw)

Comment: @Joe If you VTC as off-topic, and the question is closed, the migration will be rejected and the question will be moved back to Math.SE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [long multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_multiplication). Basic well-known math systems are not puzzles. 2+2=? is not a puzzle, nor is long multiplication

Comment: @Joe Thankfully, Raymond Smullyan didn't have this opinion when he wrote his puzzle books, where the reader is driven from simple tricks to deep mathematical logic. The same could be said of Martin Gardner by the way (for those who know his articles in Scientific American, among other treasures), and others.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut if you want to write a book on math and puzzles then go ahead, just don't post all the math bits on a puzzle site. Basic math != puzzle

Comment: I think the puzzle aspect of this question is that it's not immediately clear that the grids are using lattice multiplication. As a result, this is an interpretation puzzle, as a solver must guess the relationships between the numbers in the first two examples and apply those relationships to the third example. The fact that the puzzle uses lattice multiplication is a description of the solution, not a weakness of the puzzle.

Comment: @Kevin That's pretty obviously lattice multiplication. I mean, this originally came from Math.SE, and those guys correctly identified it as lattice multiplication, yet it got moved here anyway for no good reason. It isn't a puzzle

Answer (score 6):

Moving top to bottom on the left side...

> 1 4 2

Going right to left on the bottom...

> 6 7 7

These values in the third table, using the same method as the other two tables...

> ...multiply two three-digit values.  So the third one shows that 249 times 573 equals 142,677 (value on left, read downward, concatenated with value on bottom, read going right).  The technique is called "lattice multiplication."  It works because it's simply like multiplying any long numbers by hand.  That is, multiplying each combination of digits and summing for the appropriate values of the answer's digits in their corresponding places.  It's just a different format of writing out the calculation.

The values are calculated as follows:

> The value in each cell is its column's (top) header value multiplied by the header value to the right of its row.  Then, the product's two digits are split by a diagonal line which bisects the cell equally from top-right to bottom-left.  After that, the values in each diagonal stripe, starting on the bottom-right and moving to the top-left, are summed up, carrying any overflow into a second digit into the sum of the next stripe.  Those summed values are placed either to the bottom of the table or to its left, depending on where the diagonal stripe for the summed values end.

[EDIT:]

Thought of an easier solution:

> Just multiply the number on top of the table, read moving to the right, by the number to the right, read going down.  Then, the first three digits of the product go top to bottom on the left, and the next three digits go left to right on the bottom.  (The question is how the numbers can be computed - not that they *have* to be computed in the way implied by the table's presence, right?)

Comment: If it _does_ stay here, it needs an answer posted as such, yeah?

Answer (score 4):

These tables are examples of [lattice multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_multiplication).

Ignoring the diagonal lines, the numbers in each of the squares is the product of the number at the top of its column and the number at the right of its row. For example, in the top-left of the first example in the question, $4 \cdot 8 = 32$.

```
          4
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
|   |   |32 | 8
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

Then, in the square, write the tens digit of the product to the left of the diagonal line and the ones digit to the right of it.

```
          4
+---+---+---+
|  /|  /|3 /|
| / | / | / | 8
|/  |/  |/ 2|
+---+---+---+
|  /|  /|  /|
| / | / | / |
|/  |/  |/  |
+---+---+---+
|  /|  /|  /|
| / | / | / |
|/  |/  |/  |
+---+---+---+
```

Then, looking at the diagonal lines and ignoring the vertical and horizontal lines making the squares, we see that there are several diagonal columns going down and to the left.

```
  2   7   4
+---+---+---+
|1 / 1 / 3 /|
| /   /   / | 8
|/ 6 / 4 / 2|
+   /   /   +
|1 / 6 / 3 /|
| /   /   / | 9
|/ 8 / 3 / 6|
+   /   /   +
|1 / 3 / 2 /|
| /   /   / | 5
|/ 0 / 5 / 0|
+---+---+---+
```

For each of these diagonal columns, starting with the leftmost, add up all of the digits that are in them. Write the ones digit of the sum in the space immediately to the bottom or left of the column (where the question marks are in example 3), then carry the tens and larger digits to the next column.

In example three, the multiplication steps have already been completed. All that's left is to add up the diagonal columns. Doing so, we find that the numbers in the question marks are:

```
    2   4   9
  +---+---+---+
* |1 /|2 /|4 /|
1 | / | / | / | 5
* |/ 0|/ 0|/ 5|
  +---+---+---+
* |1 /|2 /|6 /|
4 | / | / | / | 7
* |/ 4|/ 8|/ 3|
  +---+---+---+
* |0 /|1 /|2 /|
2 | / | / | / | 3
* |/ 6|/ 2|/ 7|
  +---+---+---+
   *6* *7* *7*
```

---

Since lattice multiplication is an algorithm for multiplying, we can find the numbers in the question marks even faster: Ignore the numbers in the lattice altogether, multiply the numbers going across the top and right of the lattice, and write the product along the left and bottom of the lattice. In the case of example three, the number going across the top of the lattice is $249$, the number going down the right of the lattice is $573$, and their product is $249 \cdot 573 = 142677$.

```
    2   4   9
  +---+---+---+
* |   |   |   |
1 |   |   |   | 5
* |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+
* |   |   |   |
4 |   |   |   | 7
* |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+
* |   |   |   |
2 |   |   |   | 3
* |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+
   *6* *7* *7*
```